# Getting IgniteCheckedException: Failed to start SPI: TcpDiscoverySpi Exception

Tags: java, spring, ignite

I have installed apache ignite on openshift/Kubernetes cluster. while installing apache ignite I provided the following node-configuration.xml. I have followed [this](https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/installation/kubernetes/amazon-eks-deployment) document to install ignite cluster

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

<bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.IgniteConfiguration">

    <property name="workDirectory" value="/ignite/work"/>

    <property name="dataStorageConfiguration">
        <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.DataStorageConfiguration">
            <property name="defaultDataRegionConfiguration">
                <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.DataRegionConfiguration">
                    <property name="persistenceEnabled" value="true"/>
                </bean>
            </property>

            <property name="walPath" value="/ignite/wal"/>
            <property name="walArchivePath" value="/ignite/walarchive"/>
        </bean>

    </property>

    <property name="discoverySpi">
        <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi">
            <property name="ipFinder">
                <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ipfinder.kubernetes.TcpDiscoveryKubernetesIpFinder">
                    <constructor-arg>
                        <bean class="org.apache.ignite.kubernetes.configuration.KubernetesConnectionConfiguration">
                            <property name="namespace" value="ignite" />
                            <property name="serviceName" value="ignite-service" />
                        </bean>
                    </constructor-arg>
                </bean>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```

and in java code used the below configuration to start to ignite client

```
    IgniteConfiguration cfg = new IgniteConfiguration();
    cfg.setClientMode(true);
    cfg.setPeerClassLoadingEnabled(false);
    KubernetesConnectionConfiguration kubernetesCfg = new KubernetesConnectionConfiguration();
    kubernetesCfg.setNamespace("ignite");
    kubernetesCfg.setServiceName("ignite-service");
    TcpDiscoveryKubernetesIpFinder kubernetesIpFinder = new TcpDiscoveryKubernetesIpFinder(kubernetesCfg);
    cfg.setDiscoverySpi(new TcpDiscoverySpi().setIpFinder(kubernetesIpFinder));
```

but getting the following error while starting ignite java client.

```
> 

[ERROR] 2022-10-11 18:15:56.638 [main] IgniteKernal - Failed to start manager: GridManagerAdapter [enabled=true, name=o.a.i.i.managers.discovery.GridDiscoveryManager]
    org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Failed to start SPI: TcpDiscoverySpi [addrRslvr=null, sockTimeout=5000, ackTimeout=5000, marsh=JdkMarshaller [clsFilter=org.apache.ignite.marshaller.MarshallerUtils$1@6c302a1d], reconCnt=10, reconDelay=2000, maxAckTimeout=600000, soLinger=5, forceSrvMode=false, clientReconnectDisabled=false, internalLsnr=null, skipAddrsRandomization=false]
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.GridManagerAdapter.startSpi(GridManagerAdapter.java:280) ~[ignite-core-8.8.11.jar!/:8.8.11]
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.discovery.GridDiscoveryManager.start(GridDiscoveryManager.java:985) ~[ignite-core-8.8.11.jar!/:8.8.11]
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteKernal.startManager(IgniteKernal.java:1919) ~[ignite-core-8.8.11.jar!/:8.8.11]
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteKernal.start(IgniteKernal.java:1235) ~[ignite-core-8.8.11.jar!/:8.8.11]
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx$IgniteNamedInstance.start0(IgnitionEx.java:1784) ~[ignite-core-8.8.11.jar!/:8.8.11]
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx$IgniteNamedInstance.start(IgnitionEx.java:1706) ~[ignite-core-8.8.11.jar!/:8.8.11]
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start0(IgnitionEx.java:1143) ~[ignite-core-8.8.11.jar!/:8.8.11]
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:660) ~[ignite-core-8.8.11.jar!/:8.8.11]
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:597) ~[ignite-core-8.8.11.jar!/:8.8.11]
        at org.apache.ignite.Ignition.getOrStart(Ignition.java:410) ~[ignite-core-8.8.11.jar!/:8.8.11]
        at org.osdu.gcz.transformer.repository.ignite.DefaultFeatureCache.<init>(DefaultFeatureCache.java:64) ~[classes!/:0.17.0-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.osdu.gcz.transformer.configuration.TransformerConfiguration.remoteFeatureCache(TransformerConfiguration.java:53) ~[classes!/:0.17.0-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.osdu.gcz.transformer.configuration.TransformerConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$e666dfd2.CGLIB$remoteFeatureCache$1(
```

Comment: Please share full exception details. Inner exceptions should contain the actual reason for the failure.

Comment: It is not allowing me to add entire error trace. Exceeds thier character limits

Comment: Try GitHub Gitsts or Pastebin.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/6YDe9eW3

Answer (score 1):

Error from the [detailed log](https://pastebin.com/raw/6YDe9eW3):

`Local node and remote node have different version numbers (node will not join, Ignite does not support rolling updates, so versions must be exactly the same) [locBuildVer=8.7.12, rmtBuildVer=8.8.11`

Make sure that all nodes have the same Ignite version.

Comment: The above error has gone when I changed both versions to 8.8.11 but the IgniteCheckedException: Failed to start SPI: TcpDiscoverySpi error still exists.
updated error trace - https://pastebin.com/M3Qen865

Comment: @Bhushan please look through the exception details, the answer is there: `Incompatible data region configuration`, you have inconsistent configs on different nodes.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this method to start the client

```
@Bean
    public Ignite igniteInstance() {
        log.info("Creating ignite instance");
        TcpDiscoveryKubernetesIpFinder tcpDiscoveryKubernetesIpFinder = new TcpDiscoveryKubernetesIpFinder();
        tcpDiscoveryKubernetesIpFinder.setNamespace("default");
        tcpDiscoveryKubernetesIpFinder.setServiceName("job-cache");
 
        TcpDiscoverySpi tcpDiscoverySpi = new TcpDiscoverySpi();
        tcpDiscoverySpi.setIpFinder(tcpDiscoveryKubernetesIpFinder);
 
        IgniteConfiguration igniteConfiguration = new IgniteConfiguration();
 
        igniteConfiguration.setDiscoverySpi(tcpDiscoverySpi);
        igniteConfiguration.setClientMode(false);
 
        return Ignition.start(igniteConfiguration);
    }
```

Try adding these dependencies rather than creating bean in pom.xml

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.ignite</groupId>
            <artifactId>ignite-kubernetes</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.ignite</groupId>
            <artifactId>ignite-spring</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.6</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.ignite</groupId>
                    <artifactId>ignite-indexing</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Follow this documentataion,
[Documentation](https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2020/04/apache-ignite-and-spring-on-your-kubernetes-cluster-part-1-spring-boot-application.html) - Part 1

Comment: i have done these changes but still getting error `IgniteCheckedException: Failed to start SPI: TcpDiscoverySpi`